# AutoComplete in Landscape Not Getting Position

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

The ArrayAdapter that populates the AutoComplete drop down is returning "-1" for positions greater than 5 in landscape when I click the item.  When I have my application running in portrait, I get the correct index returned when I click and item.  Below are 2 screen shots to show how the adapter populates with data in each orientation:

EDIT:  Is there any way to force using my dropdown list rather than the phone's in landscape?

[image: Landscape Autocomplete]

[image: Portrait Autocomplete]

Not sure what may be the culprit of this?

Comment: Seeing the exact same issue, Galaxy S5

Answer (score 0):

A work around, not ideal because if a small screen phone does the same as the Samsung Galaxy S III (returning an index of -1 beyond the 6th position of the array), then the crash will still occur, I have in my code below.

```
if (!((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL)) {
            mQuery.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);
} else {
            mQuery.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH);
}
```

The HTC Wildfire has the same drop-down as the Samsung, but returns a position past the index of 5.

I will continue to investigate why the S III doesn't work, but I am rendering a guess that it is on the OS level.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old question, but I was having the same problem (I noticed this bug on a Samsung Galaxy S5).  I added adding the following code to the `performFiltering` method in my `ArrayAdapter`

```
@Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> queryResults;

            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) queryResults = getPredictions(constraint);
            else queryResults = new ArrayList<>(); // empty list/no suggestions

            //HERE'S THE IMPORTANT STUFF
            int orientation = context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
            if ((queryResults !=null) && (queryResults.size() >4) && (orientation ==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)) {
                // if user in landscape and more than four suggestions offered by Google Places
                PlaceAutocomplete item1 = queryResults.get(0);
                PlaceAutocomplete item2 = queryResults.get(1);
                PlaceAutocomplete item3 = queryResults.get(2);
                PlaceAutocomplete item4 = queryResults.get(3);
                // empty the suggestion list
                queryResults.clear();
                // add the only first four suggestion
                queryResults.add(item1);
                queryResults.add(item2);
                queryResults.add(item3);
                queryResults.add(item4);
            }

            filterResults.values = queryResults;
            if (queryResults !=null) filterResults.count = queryResults.size();

            return filterResults;
        }
```

Then just to be safe, I added a try/catch around the

```
private final AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mAutocompleteClickListener =new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        try {
            final PlaceArrayAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete item = placeArrayAdapter.getItem(position);
            final String placeId = String.valueOf(item != null ? item.placeId : null);
            final String placeDesc = String.valueOf(item != null ? item.description : null);
            PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(googleApiClient, placeId);
            placeResult.setResultCallback(mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback);
        } catch (Exception | Error exception) {
            //handle the exception (bug)
        }
    }
};
```

I tested both the try/catch and the adaper change.  Both work.